# Use font ligatures as concealment

Tags: fonts, vscode

I write tex in VSCode using the latex-studio extension, and I wanted to add concealments to the editor, for example, when I write \lambda I want it to display λ in the editor itself. I found a VSCode extension that does this, but its quite buggy and outdated, and I thought about creating a font, and achieving it with font ligatures, and was wondering if its a good idea, or is there an easier way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: why have λ write to latex as \lambda? If you want λ in the editor you could simply write λ to the latex file.

Comment: I guess that might work for some characters, but it wont work for example for ∪ for \cup or Σ for \sum.

Comment: it can easily be made to work, it would work by default with `unicode-math` or for pdftex  just add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2211}{\sum}` are you sure vscode would work with a font with ligatures, many code editors need to keep track of where the cursor is and fail if the visual font does not correspond to the underlying character string

Comment: I doubt very much that any editor cares about ligatures. Why should they?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well I'm about to change the one used at learnlatex because they break it:-) (well complicated indic script combinations actually but ligatures probably the same)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle break in which direction? Too many or not enough ligatures?

Comment: (a) The editor's font needs to have the glyph, otherwise it will probably just display what looks like a blank or something; (b) the editor's auto-correct/auto-complete feature can handle string replacements; (c) once you have `∀ ∂ ∰ θ ω π λ`, or whatever, in the editor, do you want to go in the reverse direction and recover what you typed in? (d) unrelated: `λ` is the opposite of concealment; what is it that you want to hide? Even using `^^^^XXXX` notation is not concealment.

Comment: Accessing any glyph that is not on the current keyboard (e.g., `∪∑`,, ``, ``, `ԲԳԴ`) can be done various ways: (1) direct input or a dedicated Input Method (2) keyboard swap or keyboard overlay (3) `^^^^` notation or `\symbol` command (4) auto-replace in editor (5) defined macros (6) expl3 regex/replace function ...